# Different images in buttons of menu iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I have a flyout menu made of UIButtons and I need images in each button of the menu.  I need a different image to display for each individual button that is made.  there are 6 buttons total.

How can I do this

```
- (NSInteger)makeOneButton:(NSString *)title action:(SEL)action top:(NSNumber *)top into:(UIView *)parent
{
    // NOTE: if you want more stuff here, I'd put all of the items in a view (including this button)

    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:title  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //UIButtonTypeCustom
    [button addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:7]];
    [parent addSubview:button];
    [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(top);
        make.left.equalTo(parent.mas_left);
        make.width.equalTo(parent);
        make.height.equalTo([NSNumber numberWithInteger:mCurrentCellHeight]);
    }];
    return mCurrentCellHeight;        
}
```

Comment: and the question is …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another parameter in this method which is image name or image and and add as a background of button, When u call this method to add button also tell the method which image u want to set corresponding button. Like this....

```
- (NSInteger)makeOneButton:(NSString *)title action:(SEL)action top:(NSNumber *)top  imageName:(NSString *)imageName into:(UIView *)parent
{
    // NOTE: if you want more stuff here, I'd put all of the items in a view (including this button)

    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:title  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //UIButtonTypeCustom
    [button addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:7]];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [parent addSubview:button];
    [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(top);
        make.left.equalTo(parent.mas_left);
        make.width.equalTo(parent);
        make.height.equalTo([NSNumber numberWithInteger:mCurrentCellHeight]);
    }];
    return mCurrentCellHeight;
}
```

Comment: You want to add a image on button? if yes then you pass that name on this method add set as a background image of button.